# Create a multivariate AR model in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, autoregressive-models

I want to create two vector time series in MATLAB, or Python like the following. 
`Variances = 1` and `0.7`, respectively.

```
X(t) = 0.9X(t − 1) − 0.5X(t − 2) + ε(t)
Y(t) = 0.8Y (t − 1) − 0.5Y (t − 2) + 0.16X(t − 1) − 0.2X(t − 2) + η(t)
```

How would I go about doing this... I know for X(t), I can code the following in MATLAB:

```
xmodel = arima('Constant', 0, 'AR', {0.9, -0.5}, 'Variance', 0.1);
X = simulate(xmodel, 500);
```

Can someone provide insight into how to do `Y(t)` in both MATLAB and/or Python. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Matlab you can use the arima Beta property to account for additional regression coefficients:

```
ymodel = arima('Constant',0,'AR',{0.8,-0.5},'Beta',[0.16,-0.2],'Variance',0.7)

ymodel = 

    ARIMAX(2,0,0) Model:
    ---------------------
    Distribution: Name = 'Gaussian'
               P: 2
               D: 0
               Q: 0
        Constant: 0
              AR: {0.8 -0.5} at Lags [1 2]
             SAR: {}
              MA: {}
             SMA: {}
            Beta: [0.16 -0.2]
        Variance: 0.7
```

Edit: Added command `simulate` to illustrate how to include X in the simulation of Y.

```
Y = simulate(ymodel,500,'X',X);
```

Comment: do you know how I would also do this for Python?

Comment: Also does the Beta make ymodel dependent on the xmodel? I couldn't find any good matlab documentation explaining that.

Comment: @ajl123 I don't know python enough and would have to look into the documentation myself. As for your second comment: check out the mat [works documentation about simulate](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/econ/arima.simulate.html). There it says how you can add your X-model. I'll add the example to my answer.